# how to find chef client run successful or not

Tags: api, chef-infra

I want to perform chef operations using api from my own program(java). I would like to know whether my chef client run is successful or not.

What is the best way to find this. Did chef maintains any attribute or store recent chef client run status.

Comment: More details, please

Comment: You could install the "lastrun" chef handler and associated knife plugin to display details of the last chef run on each node. Not completely fool proof but works well: https://github.com/jgoulah/knife-lastrun

Comment: Thanks Mark.. I will try this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the timestamp of the last successful run from the node data (key is `ohai_time`), but that's about it for vanilla Chef. More likely what you want is the information for specific runs, which you could get from the Reporting system (part of the Premium add-ons) or by making a custom report/error handler to ship the data to your own system.